# How can I call command line commands from python

Tags: python, command-line

How can I use command line tools like ls, grep from python.

Comment: oh you know what, I may have misunderstood this question, and answered the command line arguments part.

Answer (score 0):

This is done with [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

```
import subprocess  
subprocess.call("ls", shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package [getopt](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/getopt.html) to use command line arguments with your python code.

There is also a more advanced module called [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) that is easier to code in and provides more help and helpful error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you import os and do os.system(command) that can execute commands.

```
import os
os.system("your command here")
```

Comment: scrap this: subprocess is the way to go